# How should i write my plugin for working with "live" elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery

i'm trying to write my own autosuggest plugin, using jquery tutorial, wich should work with dynamically created fields. But i have no success.
For example:

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.dataSuggester = function(options) {

    //By using $.extend we merge predefined options with passed in plugin
    var options = $.extend({location:false, minlength:3, category:false}, options);
    var stop_keys = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 44, 45, 46, 91, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 144];

    return this.each(function() {

        var o = $(this);
        var suggestWrapper = $('<div class = "data-suggester suggest-box-wrapper">');

        o.focus(function() {
            console.log('aaaaa');
        });

        ...............................

    });

};

})( jQuery );
```

When i try to use it like

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.dataSuggest').dataSuggester();
</script>
```

It works perfect for all elements except dynamically created :(

Of course i can call my plugin in other way, like

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.dataSuggest').live('focus', function() {$(this).dataSuggester();});
</script>
```

, but i think it is not as pretty as i want.

When i try to make something like this:

```
o.live('focus', function() {console.log('aaaa');});
```

It doesn't work. Please, help me anyone?

Comment: What in the world does `but i think it is not as pretty as i want.` mean? Also capitalize your i's. :)

Comment: "but i think it is not as pretty as i want." - this mean that I think it can be solved in other(better) way, but I don't know how :) And thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.live` is an event binding function.  It works by taking the description of the wrapped set `.dataSuggest` and binding the specified event whenever a new element matching that description is found.

A jQuery plugin works by executing a function on an already selected set of elements.  These are two totally different activities.

If you want your plugin to use `.live` then it needs to, at some point, have the *description* of target elements being passed in (as opposed to a wrapped set of the target elements themselves).

Consider something like this:

```
// Plugin in use:
$.dataSuggest({ targetElements: '.customClass' });

// Plugin code:
$.fn.dataSuggester = function(options) {

    $(options.targetElements).live('focus', function(e) {
        // your code here...
    });

};
```

Note how the plugin isn't being used on a wrapped set `$('.whatever').dataSuggest()`, but instead being executed as a plain function on the jQuery object.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. This is help me to understand where I was wrong.